# Await expressions as method parameters in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, parameter-passing

A Microsoft docs tutorial introduced me to this code:

```
var repositories = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Repository>>(await streamTask);
```

I am familiar with `async` and `await` and how to use them, or so I thought. The tutorial mentions that this is an example of using an “await expression” - that’s fine, after all, the expression doesn’t look all that odd on it’s own, but I have yet to find another, single example of any C# code like this - where an await expression is being passed to a method - anywhere. The await keyword here almost looks like it’s functioning as a parameter modifier e.g. ref, out, in.

So my question is, is this a new feature, is it just rarely used, or is it just new to me? It’s functionality seems obvious, intuitive, and useful, but like I mentioned, I have yet to find another example of similar code anywhere.

Tutorial I was looking through:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient

Comment: Perfectly legal, seen it in many places. Often one doesn't directly pass through such a value because it can get difficult to debug without seeing intermediate values.

Comment: `streamTask` is probably of type `Task<Stream>`; then `await streamTask` is a `Stream`. Might be clearer to split this up in two statements: `var stream = await streamTask; var repositories = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Repository>>(stream);`. No magic going on here.

Comment: `await` is *just* an operator - not a modifier like `out`, `in` etc. There's nothing new here, and like others, I've seen this in plenty of places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have yet to find another, single example of any C# code like this - where an await expression is being passed to a method - anywhere.

It's not uncommon. As another commenter noted, `await` keywords are often split into separate lines for debuggability or readability reasons. But I've seen this kind of usage many times.

Another somewhat common pattern for `await` expressions is to use parentheses to extract part of a result:

```
var x = (await SomethingAsync()).Property;
```

> The await keyword here almost looks like it’s functioning as a parameter modifier e.g. ref, out, in.

I assume it only looks that way because it's not familiar and colored like a keyword in your editor. `await` - like `new` - is a keyword that exists in an expression.

> So my question is, is this a new feature, is it just rarely used, or is it just new to me?

New to you.

In the original `async` CTP, `await` expressions didn't work correctly and *had* to be split into separate statements. But that limitation was removed before the official `async` support was released, so `await` expressions have been supported since day 1 (ignoring prereleases).

Comment: Thank you! It through me for a loop when I couldn’t find another example, but I appreciate the answers and you taking the time to explain it clearly.

Comment: We have a number of `(await SomethingAsync()).Property` when using expression-bodied members: `public X GetXAsync() => (await GetAsync()).X`